# How to pass callable in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls, django-1.9

Hi i am new in Python and Django and I follow the [django workshop](http://www.django-workshop.de/erste_schritte/views_templates.html) guide. 
I just installed Python 3.5 and Django 1.9 and get a lot of error messages ...
Just now I found a lot of dokumentations but now stuck.
I want to add views and and so I added following code in urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rezept/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'recipes.views.detail'),
    url(r'^$', 'recipes.views.index'),
]
```

and every time get the error message:

```
Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got recipes.views.index). Pass the callable instead.
  url(r'^$', 'recipes.views.index'),
```

But I couldn't find how to pass them. The documentations only tell "pass them" but no example how to...

Comment: It seems like that guide was written for Django 1.4. Quite a lot has changed since then, so you might be better to look for a different tutorial to learn Django.

Comment: Hmm yeah thank you (=

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a deprecation warning, which means the code would still run for now. But to address this, just change

```
url(r'^$', 'recipes.views.index'),
```

to this:

```
#First of all explicitly import the view
from recipes import views as recipes_views #this is to avoid conflicts with other view imports
```

and in the URL patterns,

```
url(r'^rezept/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', recipes_views.detail),
url(r'^$', recipes_views.index),
```

[More documentation and the reasoning can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns)

> In the modern era, we have updated the tutorial to instead recommend
>   importing your views module and referencing your view functions (or
>   classes) directly. This has a number of advantages, all deriving from
>   the fact that we are using normal Python in place of “Django String
>   Magic”: the errors when you mistype a view name are less obscure, IDEs
>   can help with autocompletion of view names, etc.